# Alternative way to check if application is installed on MAC OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, launch-services

I have been using [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999) function LSFindApplicationForInfo() to check if an appication is installed.

This works fine, except when a user send the application to the trash. This method still finds it in the trash but can't invoke it.

Is there another way to check if an application is installed in /Applications? Or can I specify that I want to only look under /Applications when calling LSFindApplicationForInfo()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by checking the path to ensure it started with "/Applications".